# Why is the result an empty array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I use mongodb for my project.

when I put in this code - `db.find( {"N": {$eq:1} } )` , the result is a empty array.

but when I put this code -  `db.find({$where : function(){return(this.N==1)}})`, the result is the array that I want.

I think two codes are same. why is the result of first code an empty array?

Comment: What are the values in the database…?

Comment: can you try  `db.find({$where : function(){return(this.N === 1)}});` with === maybe N value is string not a number.

Comment: the value is number,  second code is working well. i want to know why first code is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The value is not a number as you claim, the syntax `==` is different than the strict eq operator `===` ( which is the equivalent~ of Mongo's `$eq` ) as can be seen in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

```
1 == `1`

> true
```

While the strict operator

```
1 === '1'

> false
```

So you just need to change the code to match the string '1', like so:

```
db.find( {"N": {$eq:'1'} }
```

Or if you want to support both cases:

```
db.find( {"N": {$in: [1, '1']} }
```

I recommend you fix your schema and db to make sure it's aligned to what you believe the structure should be.